# How to disable rendering of parent element if child attribute is true

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, parent-child

I want to disable the rendering of the parent TR element if the third child TD's attribute is equal to true.

Is there a way to use a ternary operator on the parent element to check if the child elements attribute is true or false?

```
 // Setting my GET request response data to users

 componentDidUpdate() {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
     .then(response => {
       this.setState({ users: response.data });
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     })
 }

  // Mapping my data from GET request to the proper table and 
  using a ternary operator to check if GET data group is equal to 
  the current group and setting to true or false

  <tbody>
    {this.state.users.map(function (singleuser, i) {
      return [
       <tr key={i} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <td>{singleuser.name}</td>
        <td>{singleuser.email}</td>
        <td selected={user.group.toString() === singleuser.group.toString()}>{singleuser.group}</td>
      </tr>
      ]
   })}
 </tbody>
```

Comment: what do you mean by disable rendering of the parent?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I just don't want to render that particular TR element

Comment: apply css like `display: none;`? or actually not render?

Comment: I'd prefer not to render it, but a display: none will work as well. @JohnRuddell

Comment: ok and what is the check for true? `user.group.toString() === singleuser.group.toString()` ?

Comment: That's to check if the user.group value is the same as the singleuser.group value. If it is, it sets the selected attribute to true.

Comment: yes so when you say `if the third child TD's attribute is equal to true` are you saying that the selected attribute is the one to use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194558/discussion-between-seth-spivey-and-john-ruddell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a conditional to not render the item

```
<tbody>
    {this.state.users.map(function (singleuser, i) {
      const shouldHide = user.group.toString() === singleuser.group.toString()
      return shouldHide
        ? null
        : <tr key={i} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
            <td>{singleuser.name}</td>
            <td>{singleuser.email}</td>
            <td selected={shouldHide}>{singleuser.group}</td>
          </tr>
     })
   }
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you John

Comment: Yep! just so you know, if you want to keep it and apply a display style. You would just use the `shouldHide` variable, and put it on the tr style `style={{ color: '#fff', display: shouldHide ? 'none' : 'block'}}` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional rendering to display it, or something else.
Something along the lines of...

```
const enabled = this.state.enabled;
{enabled ? <tr> <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>:'no table row'}
```

Here is a code pen example I made. You can change the true/false by updating state
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNoEjQ

Comment: Check out the inline if-else with conditional rendering section on this page https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html